# Архивация бд mysql в php

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно сделать экспорт БД. Чтобы простой пользователь смог например одним нажатием сохранить бд у себя на компе, как phpmyadmin. Это возможно?

Answer (score 2):

Так а в чем проблема? Можно дать доступ к PMA, можно вручную средствами php собрать запросы в файл, можно сделать exec('mysqldump <ляляля>') (ну, для *nix систем точно прокатит), ну и соотв. выбросить это пользователю.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл вот такой скрипт!

```
backup_database_tables('localhost','root','root','method', '*');
// backup the db function
function backup_database_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name,$tables)
{
        $link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
        mysql_select_db($name,$link);
        //get all of the tables
        if($tables == '*')
        {
                $tables = array();
                $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
                while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
                {
                        $tables[] = $row[0];
                }
        }
        else
        {
                $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
        }
        //cycle through each table and format the data
        foreach($tables as $table)
        {
                $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
                $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);
                //$return.= '';
                $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
                $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";
                for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++)
                {
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
                        {
                                $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
                                for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++)
                                {
                                        $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                                        $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
                                        if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
                                        if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
                                }
                                $return.= ");\n";
                        }
                }
                $return.="\n\n\n";
        }
        //save the file
        $date=date('d-m-Y');
        $handle = fopen('db-testi- '.$date.'.sql','w+');
        fwrite($handle,$return);
        fclose($handle);
}
```

Вроде отлично работает! Просто если были сложные mysql запросы я всегда обращался в PMA и копировал запросы! А когда делаешь запрос экспорта то pma не выводит! Вот и думал! А этот скрипт вроде работает корректно!

Comment: Есть у меня одна табличка на ~50млн записей..) Там бы выборку записей в цикле штук по 100 хотя бы и было б очень хорошо.

Answer (score 1):

Не изобретайте велосипеды)
есть потрясающая утилита Sypex Dumper, версия лайт просто класс, пользуюсь ей, бесплатная.

http://sypex.net/ru/products/dumper/downloads/
я кстати на основе их скрипта писал скрипт который отправлял мне бекапы на мыло.. но это актуально для небольших баз

Comment: Зависит от потребностей пользователя. Если ему необходимо просто отдать базу, почему бы это не сделать стандартной утилитой mysqldump? Надо отметить, что она довольно функциональная. С другой стороны там есть ряд вопросов, связанных с безопасностью при использовании exec, но по-хорошему в самом вопросе опущены ряд важных условий и поэтому приходится гадать :)